# Pylab, draw a probability distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib

im using pylab for scientific computing purposes. I ve made a histogram with the hist method. But im also interested in painting a probability distribution. Does someone know of that?

Comment: A more specific question would be helpful. Ex., this is what I have tried, this is the error I get.

Comment: you could try matplotlib, ob their website there is a lot of examples in the gallery, choose the one most similar to your needs, and starting from there, modify it until you get what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Scipy has many probability distributions [built in](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html), some function example from the docs (of many):

> `norm`:   A normal continuous random variable.
>
> `alpha`:  An alpha continuous random variable.
>
> `beta`:   A beta continuous random variable.
>
> `chi`:    A chi continuous random variable.
>
> `erlang`: An Erlang continuous random variable.
>
> `gamma`:  A gamma continuous random variable.
>
> ...

Some examples on how to draw from the distribution and plot the `norm, beta, chi and alpha`:

```
from scipy.stats import *
from pylab import hist, show,subplot

N = 2000

subplot(221)
X = norm.rvs(size=N)
hist(X,normed=True,bins=30)

subplot(222)
X = beta.rvs(2,1,size=N)
hist(X,normed=True,bins=30)

subplot(223)
X = chi.rvs(2.0, size=N)
hist(X,normed=True,bins=30)

subplot(224)
X = gamma.rvs(1.0, size=N)
hist(X,normed=True,bins=30)
show()
```

[image]